# django-filter: only show filter options contained in queryset

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

I'm using the excellent django-filter app to filter a queryset of model objects. However, when I .exclude() objects from the queryset in the view, the filter selectors in the template still show all available options - even those of objects I excluded from the queryset. Let's say my model and view look as follows:

```
#model
[...]
class Animal(models.Model):
    REGION_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Africa'),
        (1, 'Europe'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region = models.CharField(choices=REGION_CHOICES, max_length=100)
[...]

#view  
[...]  
qs = Animal.objects.all()
filter = AnimalFilter(request.GET, qs)
[...]
```

Assuming there are two animals in the database:

```
zebra = Animal(name='Zebra', region='Africa')
frog = Animal(name='Frog', region'Europe')
```

When I render the filter in the template, I correctly get a selector for region which contains the two options Europe and Africa.
But if I use some logic in the view to .exclude() objects from the queryset like this:

```
#view
[...]
qs = Animal.objects.all().exclude(name='Frog')
filter = AnimalFilter(request.GET, qs)
[...]
```

Now if I render the filter in the template I still get the two options *Europe* and *Africa* for region although the queryset only contains one animal which has the region *Africa*.
Any ideas how I could get the correct options for the region field rendered in the template? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `choices` in your `FilterSet.__init__()` to ensure that the region choices are limited to the regions based on the provided queryset.

```py
class AnimalFilter(FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnimalFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        regions = self.queryset.values('region').distinct()
        region_choices = [(k, v) for k, v in REGION_CHOICES if k in regions]
        self.filters['region'].choices = region_choices
```

Note: I haven't tested this, but should hopefully be enough to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sherpa almost had it:

```
class AnimalFilter(FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #we are going to need the form underneath the filter, so init parent
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #use a flat values list to get a queryset list good enough for this
        #can wrap in list() to force evaluation and get list of values only
        regions = self.queryset.values_list('region',flat=True).distinct()
        region_choices = [(k, v) for k, v in REGION_CHOICES if k in regions]
        #filter hands off to subclassed form for widgets, attach there
        self.form.fields['region'].choices = region_choices
```